# How to create words from an array of characters

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program which will prompt the user for 9 characters. Once these characters are in the program the program should create the longest word possible using these letters by comparing them against a dictionary file.

The program currently stores the 9 letters and reads in the dictionary file, but i have no idea where to start regarding the word creation.

All i need help with is the word creator. If someone knows how to create words from characters in an array can you give me a hand

Comment: Actually, you're not "creating" a word, after all it needs to exist in the dictionary. You're *finding* a word that contains all of those letters (and only those letters). I'd suggest this approach: for each word in the dictionary, check if it contains every letter and doesn't contain any other ones (if you allow duplicate letters in the 9 characters, then you'll need to check the frequency as well).

Comment: what are the constraints to this word? does it have to contain ALL characters? ONLY those characters?

Comment: The word can use as many or as little letters as it can. If you have ever seen the TV game show countdown it works in that way

Comment: More specifically the program is trying to find the longest possible word from the given letters. It should then display that word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause it seems like you don´t get the solution, here is mine, it should be working

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test{
public String[] dict = new String[] {"hi","das","bad","fenster","esel","bahi","tfshi"};
public char[] input = new char[]{'a','b','d','h','i','s','f','t'};
public String longestString = dict[0];

public Test() {
    System.out.println(longestString);
    ArrayList<String> convert = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String counter : dict)
        convert.add(counter);
    getInstance(convert, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("\n\n\n" + longestString);


}


private void getInstance(ArrayList<String> searching, int pos, int length, int starter, int currentI) {
        int i = starter;
        do{

            ArrayList<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String counter : searching) {
                if(counter.length() > pos) {
                    if(counter.charAt(pos) == input[i]){
                        matched.add(counter);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(matched.size() > 0) {
                getInstance(matched, pos+1,length,(i+1)%length, i%length);
            }
            else if(currentI != i && matched.size() > 0) {
                getInstance(searching,pos,length,(i+1)%length, i%length);
            }
            if(matched.size() > 0 && longestString.length() < matched.get(0).length()){
                longestString = searching.get(0);
            }
            ++i;
            i %= length;
        }while(i != currentI);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();

}
}
```

EDIT: you should fix it a bit, i just found a mistake in there

Comment: The if(counter.charAt(pos) ==input[i]0 doesnt work, every time i run the program it doesnt find a word, instead it returns null. My lecturer suggested that i should compare instead of ==. Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should go the other way: iterate through your dictionary file and check for each word whether it consists entirely of the specified letters.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the user Allrdy typed in the 9 chars and the dictionary is stored in an Array:

you are using an char array i guess? a dictionary is normally sorted i guess, so the array would be either in my conidtion.

you should scan the array with a for loop

```
// these are the scanned chars
char[] char = new chars[];
// has to be loaded from somewhere.
String[] dic = new String[100];
String found = "";
//.....reading chars
String longest = "";
for(int i = 0 : i<9;++i) {
    // look if an element exists, matching the letter a at the beginning
    if(exists) {
         // you found a word? nice safe it in a variable called found otherise compare longest and found, to check which once length is greater
         found = foundWordBefore;
         for(int j = (i+1)%10;j!=i+9%10;++j) {
         // look if there is another word matching the first letter and the second one
             if(exists) {
                 for(int k = (i+2)%10;k!=i+9%10;++k) {
                     //same again as before, continue until you reached last (i+8)%9                  

                 }
             }
         }
    }
    else {
        // if you found the nothing, compare the longest you found yet, to the longest you found before 
        if(longest.length < found.length) {
            longest = found;
        }
    }
}
```

hope this pseudo helps and works :D

Comment: so just to clarify, what did you call the dictionary array in this code

Comment: ah sorry i did not name it in here

Comment: If it helps you understand the purpose of the program it is based on the tv game show countdown

Comment: but do make it more clear, when i wrote `if(exists)`, you have to iterate throught the whole dictionary. in the first loop, for example, you have to check if in any of your Strings in your dictionary, has an `getCharAt(0)` equal to your `chars[i]`, in the second your have to check if any of your Chars on pos 2 matches : `CharAt(1)` is equal to chars[j].

Comment: you can also build in more conditions. for example you can also check in the FOR loop if you already found a word with a length of 9 and break the whole search. you can also do some subArrays, where you save the ones matching your first,second, third char and so on. This will save a lot of time, because you don´t allways compare the whole dictionary, instead of comparing only the ones matching your first condition. What i wrote down is just the basic, and can increased in many different ways